# JavaScript - match object in array and remove or add

Tags: javascript, arrays, vue.js

I'm trying to find and remove an object from an array, or push it to the array based on if it already exists. I've tried a for if loop and forEach loop and can't seem to crack it. Here's what I have so far:

```
        // object in store to be modified
        this.sorts = [
          { field: "title", direction: "asc" },
          { field: "value", direction: "asc" }, // remove if exists, add if not
          { field: "quality", direction: "asc" },
        ];

        <button @click="handleCheckbox('value', 'asc')">Value</button>; // example

        handleCheckbox(field, dir) {
        this.sorts.forEach((field, i) => {
          if (this.sorts[i].field === field) {
            this.sorts = this.sorts.splice(i, 1); // remove if passed field is found in array
            console.log("deleted=", this.sorts[i]);
            return;
          } else {
            this.sorts.push({ field: field, direction: dir }); // add if passed field is not found
            console.log("pushed=", this.sorts[i]);
            return;
          }
        });
        // state.commit("setSorts", this.sorts);
        }
```

Comment: Use `.findIndex()` to find the entry. If the index is not -1, then splice it out; otherwise push the new entry.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `findIndex` and then push the object into array accordingly.

```
var arr = [
  { field: "title", direction: "asc" },
  { field: "value", direction: "asc" }, // remove if exists, add if not
  { field: "quality", direction: "asc" },
];

function findObject(obj, value) {
  var index = arr.findIndex(function(item) {
    if (item.field === value) {
      return true;
    }
  });

  if (!index) { 
    arr.push(obj);
  }
}

findObject({ field: "value", direction: "asc" }, 'value');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use findIndex to obtain the index of the object whose field is as the `field` argument passed to the function and push or splice depending on the index.
Here's a possible implementation of the solution using vanillaJs

```js
var sorts = [
          { field: "title", direction: "asc" },
          { field: "value", direction: "asc" },
          { field: "quality", direction: "asc" },
        ];

function handleCheckbox(field, direction) {
  var index = sorts.findIndex(function(sort){
    sort.field == field
    // test checks: console.log(sort.field, field)
  });
    // test checks: console.log(index)
  if (index < 0) { 
    sorts.push({ field, direction});
  }else{
     sorts.splice(index, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
let sorts = [
    { field: "title", direction: "asc" },
    { field: "value", direction: "asc" },
    { field: "quality", direction: "asc" },
];

function handleCheckbox(field, direction) {
    let index = sorts.findIndex(sort => sort.field == field);

    if (index === -1) {
        sorts.push({ field: field, direction: direction });
        return;
    }

    sorts.splice(index, 1);
}

handleCheckbox("value", "asc");
console.log(sorts); // sorts = [ { field: "title", direction: "asc" }, { field: "quality", direction: "asc" } ];

handleCheckbox("new", "asc");
console.log(sorts); // sorts = [ { field: "title", direction: "asc" }, { field: "quality", direction: "asc" }, { field: "new", direction: "asc" } ];
```